# Sharepoint : How to create new Document locally?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to create new document from my client app , rather than from online is it possible to open word and excel client application when clicking New from Document library ?

[image]

Looking forward for your  suggestion..thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to open word and excel client application when clicking New from Document library.

You could open the file in client only after it is created in online.